# Checking whether the relationship between a mapping and its inverse is true

Tags: real-analysis, functions, discrete-mathematics, set-theory, relations

We have the following question for our homework-

> Determine whether each of the following statements is true or false. If the statement is true, prove your answer.  (Admittedly, some of these are hard to provide a proof for that is anything more than just  citing a definition, but do your best.) If the statement is false, provide a counterexample.  (In the statements below, $f:A\rightarrow B$, $E\subseteq A$ and $S\subseteq B$.)
>
> a If $x\in f^{-1}(S)$, then $f(x)\in S$.
>
> b If $y\in S$, then there exists $x\in f^{-1}(S)$ such that $f(x) = y$.
>
> c If $y\in f(E)$, then there exists $x\in E$ such that $f(x) = y$.
>
> d If $y\in f(f^{-1}(S))$, then $y\in S$.
>
> e If $x\in f^{-1}(f(E))$, then $x\in E$.

I have an answer for each, but I'm not sure if this is correct (some of my friends got different answers).

a. False. Let $f^{-1}(x)= x^2$. Thus $f(x)= \sqrt{x}$. For $x=4 $, we have both  $f(x)=2$ and $f(x)=-2$, but 2 and -2 can be in different sets.

b. True. This is the definition of an inverse.

(c)~True. Since y is in f(E), every value,x, in E must have a corresponding match such that $f(x)=y$

d. False. Is only true for surjective functions, since we $f^{-1}(S)$ might not exist always.

e. False. Only true for injective functions.

Am I correct? If not, where am I wrong? Any input would help.

Comment: $f^{-1}(S)$ always exists:  it's a set.  It might be empty, but it still exists.

Comment: Please do not rely on images to convey key information not otherwise present in your post. [Here is the explanation of why this is bad practice.](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/34121/742).

Comment: Okay. Will make the change

Answer (score 1, accepted):

a) True, actually, by the definition of a pre-image. Your counterexample doesn't work because $f(x) =x^2$ is not invertible, so $f^{-1}(x)$ doesn't exist (at least if you're defining it as $f: \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$).

b) False, because $S$ may not be mapped to by any element

c) True

d) True. As Randall mentioned, the pre-image of a set $f^{-1}(S)$ always exists even though $f^{-1}(x)$ may not. $y$ is in the image of the pre-image of $S$, and since functions only map each $x$ to one $f(x)$, it must be that $y \in S$.

e) False. If we take the image of a set $S$, and then take its pre-image, we will end up with $S$ and other elements that mapped to the same things $S$ did. So $f^{-1}(f(E))$ contains more elements other than $E$.

Comment: Can you explain d to me?

Comment: Unless I am mistaken, both (b) and (e) are false. This can be seen by taking a non-surjective function for $f$ and then letting $S=B$ and $E=Im(f)$. For (b) simply choose $y$ not in $Im(f)$ and for (e) choose $x$ not in $Im(f)$. Additionally (d) should be true, consider that for all $x$ in $f^{-1}(S)$, $f(x) \in S$ so $f(f^{-1}(S)) \subseteq S$. Please tell me if I have made some major error.

Comment: @Fishbane, yes that's right for b)! But actually

Comment: @Fishbane I'm not sure I understand your argument for e). What does $x \not \in Im(f)$ accomplish? And by $Im(f)$ do you mean $Im(S)$?

Comment: @2469158533 Actually my choice of example for $E$ doesn't work because it isn't in the right set, but if instead we choose $f$ non-injective and $E=A-\{x\}$ so that $f(x) \in f(E)$ then indeed (e) is false.

Comment: @2469158533 The two statements you give are (almost) true, but they do not let us conclude that (d) is false and (e) is true. For any sets $X \subseteq Y$ if we choose $y \in Y$ we cannot say that $y \in X$. Similarly for any $x \in X$ we can see $x \in Y$. This means that the statements you gave do not prove what you say they should. (Additionally the second statement is not always strict although it can be made to be so). You appear to be talking about the reverse of statements (d) and (e).

Comment: @Fishbane Yes that's right—I was proving the other direction. Should be fixed now!

Comment: @2469158533 Looks good. Happy to help.

Comment: Can you explain D to me? @2469158533

Comment: @pasha What still doesn't make sense?

Comment: Nvm that makes sense. But for e, is my explanation wrong? I couldn't quite understand why your work was different than mine. @2469158533